# How to display the data of a user accessing the web?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When a user accesses the web through the login, the data should appear in a table, instead, the data of all registered users appear.
How can I make it so that it only shows the data of the user who has logged in?

Connection to the database:

```
<?php

include('../php/.env.php');

class DB {

    public static function conn()
    {
        // conexión a la base de datos
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . SERVIDOR . ";dbname=" . BD, USUARIO, PASSWORD);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $conn;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'HA FALLADO LA CONEXIÓN: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

datos.php

```
<?php


include('./DB.php');

    session_start(); // I've added this and it's working

    $conexion = DB::conn();
    $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE idUser = :idUser";
    $consulta = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);;
    $consulta->execute(array(':idUser' => $_SESSION['usuario'][0]));

    $json = [];
    while ($row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = [
            'idUser' => $row['idUser'],
            'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
            'apellidos' => $row['apellidos'],
            'telefono' => $row['telefono'],
            'direccion' => $row['direccion']
        ];
    }

    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
```

MYSQL
users_data contains: idUser, first name, last name, phone number, address

JAVASCRIPT

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "datos.php", // solicita a datos.php
    success: (response) => {
      let datos = JSON.parse(response);
      let template = "";

      datos.forEach((dato) => {
        // recorre y muestra los datos de los usuarios
        template += `
          <tr>
            <td>${dato.idUser}</td>
            <td>${dato.nombre}</td>
            <td>${dato.apellidos}</td>
            <td>${dato.telefono}</td>
            <td>${dato.direccion}</td>
          </tr>
        `;
      });
      $('#datos').html(template);
    },
  });
```

Comment: Change your query to include a `WHERE` clause which uses the user-id to limit the data. How does your code "know" which user is logged in - in a session var or similar?

Comment: As an aside, `} catch (PDOException $e) { echo 'HA FALLADO LA CONEXIÓN: ' . $e->getMessage(); }` is completely pointless. You don't need a try/catch here. If the connection fails, it's unlikely your program can usefully continue, so what you actually want to happen is it errors and stops. By catching the error, you're allowing it to continue...what would happen then is you get a different error when it then fails to run a query, because there's no valid connection. And echoing exception data to the screen deliberately is a security risk - live errors should be logged to disk instead.

Comment: P.S. You need to write in English here so we can all understand you. If you feel more comfortable using Spanish, ask your question at [es.so] instead.

Comment: @droopsnoot when a user logs in, it is first checked that it exists and then stored in $_SESSION['user'].

Comment: Ok. So you can use that as a parameter in a SQL WHERE clause, to restrict the results to only ones relating to that user. Are you familiar with how a SQL WHERE clause works? If not, not would be a very good time to learn this useful info.

Comment: @ADyson yes, I have tried to put in the query : "SELECT * FROM users_data WHERE idUser = :idUser" but it doesn't work, I don't know if I need to add some more code in the php or js.

Comment: "doesn't work" means what? Do you get a specific error, or unexpected result? Please always be specific when describing a problem...remember we can't see your screen. Obviously you have to send the session value as a parameter, in the array that you need to pass to your execute() function, containing the list of parameters and their values. Have you worked with PDO parameters before? If not, there is plenty of documentation and examples showing you what to do.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You don't need bindParam _and_ passing an array to execute(). Choose one way or the other. You won't find examples which show both being done at the same time! And does `$_SESSION['usuario'][0]` contain what you expected? You still didn't mention what the actual error or problem was.

Comment: @ADyson I've updated the php code in the question, and it doesn't give any error (in console either), but it doesn't show anything in the table.
If I do a console.log(response) in the js, it returns an empty array.

Comment: If it simply returned no rows, then probably whatever you passed in from the Session didn't contain a valid user ID which matched anything in the database. Have you debugged what that Session value actually contains, as I suggested above?

Comment: @ADyson I added a session_start() and now it does show the logged in user's data

Comment: Ah yes, that would solve it.